# Exception while executing Docker command in Jenkinsfile

Tags: node.js, shell, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a test project for end2end tests based on `Nightwatch.js` that is an `NodeJS` framework. I want to use 'Jenkinsfile' for my project to build a pipeline for my end2end tests to execute them over a `Jenkins` in a `Docker container`. So, I want to start a `Docker container` and execute the tests inside this `Docker container`. And this should be realized over a `Jenkinsfile`. Everything is perfect when I don't use a `Jenkinsfile` but directly use `shell commands` in a manually created job. While using `Jenkinsfile` I get an `MultipleCompilationErrorsException` while running the pipeline and I don't know why.

This is my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  parameters {
    text(defaultValue: 'grme/nightwatch-chrome-firefox:0.0.3', description: '', name: 'docker_image')
    text(defaultValue: 'npm-test-chrome', description: '', name: 'run_script_method')
    text(defaultValue: '/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker', description: '', name: 'docker')
  }

  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'sudo chmod -R 777 $(pwd)'
        echo "------ stop all Docker containers ------"
        sh '(sudo ${params.docker} stop $(sudo ${params.docker} ps -a -q) || echo "------ all Docker containers are still stopped ------")'
        echo "------ remove all Docker containers ------"
        sh '(sudo ${params.docker} rm $(sudo ${params.docker} ps -a -q) || sudo echo "------ all Docker containers are still removed ------")'
        echo "------ pull Docker image from Docker Cloud ------"
        sh 'sudo ${params.docker} pull "${params.docker_image}"'
        echo "------ start Docker container from image ------"
        sh 'sudo ${params.docker} run -d -t -i -v $(pwd):/my_tests/ "${params.docker_image}" /bin/bash'
        echo "------ execute end2end tests on Docker container ------"
        sh 'sudo ${params.docker} exec -i $(sudo ${params.docker} ps --format "{{.Names}}") bash -c "cd /my_tests && xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1600x1200x24' npm run ${params.run_script_method} || true && google-chrome --version && firefox --version"'
        echo "------ cleanup all temporary files ------"
        sh 'sudo rm -Rf $(pwd)/tmp-*'
        sh 'sudo rm -Rf $(pwd)/.com.google*'
        sh 'sudo rm -Rf $(pwd)/rust_mozprofile*'
        sh 'sudo rm -Rf $(pwd)/.org.chromium*'
        echo "------ stop all Docker containers again ------"
        sh '(sudo ${params.docker} stop $(sudo ${params.docker} ps -a -q) || sudo echo "------ all Docker containers are still stopped ------")'
        echo "------ remove all Docker containers again ------"
        sh '(sudo ${params.docker} rm $(sudo ${params.docker} ps -a -q) || sudo echo "------ all Docker containers are still removed ------")'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the exception I get when running the pipeline:

```
Started by user GRme
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://github.com/GRme/e2e-web-tests
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/GRme/e2e-web-tests # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 1 remote branch
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 0eb7d8c437df1efc56e46171d945e7f2806b838b
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 23: Expected a symbol @ line 23, column 9.
           sh 'sudo ${params.docker} exec -i $(sudo ${params.docker} ps --format "{{.Names}}") bash -c "cd /my_tests && xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1600x1200x24' npm run ${params.run_script_method} || true && google-chrome --version && firefox --version"'
           ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:516)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:479)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:269)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Finished: FAILURE
```

What do I wrong and how can I solve this exception?

Comment: I suspect the fact that the single quotes here -server-args='...' are nested within the sh '...'

Comment: Yes I think you are right, but it should be possible to do something like this. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

After escaping the `'` in the line, the pipeline has no syntax error anymore :)

```
sh 'sudo ${params.docker} exec -i $(sudo ${params.docker} ps --format "{{.Names}}") bash -c "cd /my_tests && xvfb-run --server-args=\'-screen 0 1600x1200x24\' npm run ${params.run_script_method} || true && google-chrome --version && firefox --version"'
```